# O parâmetro oauth_consumer_key esta faltando

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript, angular

fiz a instalação local do wordpress
Tenho a minha api funcionando localmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com o erro:

```
polyfills.js:3 GET http://localhost/wordpress/wc-api/v3/products?page=2&oauth_nonce=8eGbEK9Mr8…rsion=1.0&oauth_signature=gV6ZTiZ5kWpcHTgaIfSrDXJyPp4cxljtjosSxSkUL%2BM%3D 404 (Not Found)
```

```html
this.WooCommerce = WC({
  url: "http://wooionic.esy.es",
  version: 'v3', // WooCommerce API version (optional)
  verifySsl: false, // Use `false` when need test with self-signed certificates, default is `true` (optional)
  encoding: 'utf8', // Encode, default is 'utf8' (optional)
  consumerKey: "ck_c5b919fa658a9d22a2a013326c18555a8b3c6c26",
  consumerSecret: "cs_b4b307338741da37cb7c4f96e299dfbb908f8d53"
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Após fazer a criação de um novo projeto e importar o npm deu certo, eu acredito que teve algum conflito porque eu tinha instalado um npm errado